# Null pointer exception in MediaRouter.dispatchRouteVolumeChanged

Tags: android, media-player, android-4.2-jelly-bean

On Jelly Bean 4.2.2, I'm getting a crash in the `MediaRouter` class when changing the volume on the device.

The logcat looks like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at android.media.MediaRouter.dispatchRouteVolumeChanged(MediaRouter.java:723)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at android.media.MediaRouter.systemVolumeChanged(MediaRouter.java:742)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at android.media.MediaRouter$VolumeChangeReceiver.onReceive(MediaRouter.java:2087)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:758)
E/AndroidRuntime(15239):    ... 9 more
```

I tried adding a volume change callback as follows:

```
public void onRouteVolumeChanged(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRouteVolumeChanged: info=" + info);
}
```

but I still get the crash.  I can easily reproduce the problem on 4.2.2, but have not been able to reproduce it on earlier versions of Android, so I'm getting the feeling it may be a bug in Android itself.

**I have two questions:**

1. Is there a fix or workaround for this problem?
2. How/where would I report this problem to Google (or check to see if it's already been reported/fixed)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in the debugger and set a breakpoint after you assign (a) value(s). While the debugger is paused, check the value(s) of the variable(s). If it reads "null", then it has not been assigned a proper value or has not been initialized. Sorry if this is a bit blunt; I will change this answer if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I know how to check for an NPE, however this is inside the [MediaRouter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRouter.html) class (API 16), not in my code.

Comment: Was the library source code ever edited? Another way of checking is that you can download and replace just that section of the API 16 library. Here's where you can download API 16 separately from the other package http://www.hariadi.org/android/manual-download-of-android-sdk-components/